# How can I make a custom validator of an image in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

So I have an existing database of users. I want new users that sign up to add an avatar otherwise they should get an error asking them to upload an avatar.

Looks like i have to add a file in app/models/validators

For the validation I was thinking sth along the lines of this logic :
`if avatar.attached? == false errors.add(:avatar, 'required')`

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can't you add validation in controller itself? when the params[:avatar] is empty throwing an error saying avatar is required?

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader

  validates :photo, presence: true, unless: :photo_errors_exist?

  def photo_errors_exist?
    errors[:photo].present?
  end
```